# Obtain injection point list from @RequestScope bean

Tags: jsf, cdi

I have `@RequestScoped` (RequestBean) CDI bean which is injected into two different `@ViewScope` JSF `@ManagedBean`'s (`FirstViewBean` and `SecondViewBean`). I want obtain list of RequestBean's injection points. How can I do it? Listing is bellow.

**RequestBean:**

```
@RequestScoped
public class RequestBean {

    public void logPoints() {
          System.out.println(getInjectionPoints());
    }

    private List<InjectionPoint> getInjectionPoints() {
          List<InjectionPoint> result = null;
          // ...
          return result;
    }
}
```

**FirstViewBean:**

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class FirstViewBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1867903409268465766L;

    @Inject
    private RequestBean rb;

    public void action() {
          rb.logPoints();
    }
}
```

**SecondViewBean:**

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class SecondViewBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1867903409268465766L;

    @Inject
    private RequestBean rb;

    public void action() {
        rb.logPoints();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if this code worked wouldn't it always say that List<InjectionPoint> size is always 1 because you inject it to view scoped beans? And beside that isn't InjectionPoint obtainable only for non proxyable pesudo-scopes (`@Dependent`, `@Singleton`). "*Only dependent objects, may obtain information about the injection point to which they belong.*" https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/InjectionPoint.html. Maybe say what do you need InjectionPoint for.

Comment: @Geinmachi theese words `Only dependent objects, may obtain information about the injection point to which they belong`
are applied exclusively for explained way of obtaining `InjectPoint`. Am I wrong?
I think, for 2 `@ViewScope` beans it can return 2 `InjectPoint` (e.g. when one `@ViewScope` is called from `action` and second one is called from `actionListener`).
In my case I have multiple `@ViewScope` beans (but one instanced for HTTP-request) and I want send callback just to instanced `@ViewScope` bean when `@RequestScope` bean is called